# Confluent Kafka Python producer not producing with ACKS= all configuration

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

I have a some python code that will produce into a kafka topic, this works fine with the default setting `acks=1` but when I change to `acks=all` or `acks=2` the message does not end up in the topic. the `min.insync.replicas` config on the topic is set to `2`. There is no error message returned after running the code which is confusing? There is 3 brokers in the cluster.

Here is the code

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError

def get_producer_config():
    return Producer(get_config())


def get_config():
    conf = {
        'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
        'acks': '2',
    }

    return conf

try:
    producer = get_producer_config()
    producer.produce('test', 'test message from local app')
    producer.flush()
except KafkaError as error:
    get_logger().error(str(error))
```

This stems from debugging a kafka producer lambda where we were getting the error message `KafkaError{code=NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS,val=19,str="Broker: Not enough in-sync replicas"}`
I was trying top replicate locally but a not getting the error but have noticed this while trying.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Acks: 2 - is not allowed.

> The number of acknowledgments the producer requires the leader to have received before considering a request complete. Allowed values: 0 for no acknowledgments, 1 for only the leader and -1 (or `all`) for the full ISR.

2. You have to check , topic level configuration. Two parameters are relevant.
   `min.insync.replicas(ISR) <= replication-factor`

Answer (score 3):

The acks can have only three values:

1. `acks = 1`: This is the default value where only the leader writes the message to its log but will respond without awaiting full acknowledgement from all followers.
2. `acks = 0`: the producer will not wait for any acknowledgement from the server at all. The record will be immediately added to the socket buffer and considered sent.
3. `acks =all`: This means the leader will wait for the full set of in-sync replicas to acknowledge the record. This guarantees that the record will not be lost as long as at least one in-sync replica remains alive. This is the strongest available guarantee.

Also, specify a valid value in your `min.insyn.replica` which should contain the no. of replicas including the leader.

For example, if your replication factor is 4, and your min.insync.replica = 3, it is a valid configuration for acks=all.

Answer (score 0):

FYI- According to this page
https://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html
other values such as ACKS=2 **ARE** allowed, not just 0, 1 or ALL

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).